# what OOP library do I use for 2D vector graphics reasoning, collision detection etc?

Tags: collision-detection, computational-geometry, vector-graphics, 2d-games

suppose I want to make a simple 2D "arcade" game with polygonal players that move around, shoot straight, are targeted by explosions and similar. This seems to require lots of geometric computations to figure out which polygon is intersected by a line, collisions between players and landscape obstacles, what polygons collide with the circle representing an explosion etc.

Is there a nice ready-made object oriented library that would handle all this stuff for me? .NET or ActionScript code would be ideal, but I am fine with C++ as well if no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

by ready-made you mean just add a title? wheres the fun in that? if your looking at C++ then you could use DarkGDK... ive heard its quite easy to learn but last time i checked they dont have a patch for visual studio 2010 if your using that. Id prefer something like OpenSceneGraph... its abit nasty to learn at first but once you do, it allows you to go onto other things later on like OpenGL nicely. With regards to other languages there are probably alot of templates out there. Whats it going to be for?